# Why doesn't my AVURLAsset have a duration?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

In my iOS app (SDK 5.6), I create an AVURLAsset from a short video, like so:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:nil];
```

This seems to work fine. If I examine the asset in gdb, it looks like this:

```
(gdb) po asset
<AVURLAsset: 0x1a1c40, URL = file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/A2142D8E-BC19-4E0B-A4C8-ABED4F7D4970/Documents/sample_iTunes.mov>
```

I use a sample .mov file from the Apple website, stored in the app's Documents directory.

I would like to know the duration of this video, for further processing, but when I examine the duration property, I get this:

```
(gdb) po asset.duration
There is no member named duration.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to determine the duration of an AVAsset or AVAssetTrack?

TIA: John

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating the asset, however, does not necessarily mean that it’s ready for use. To be used, an asset must have loaded its tracks. Load the asset with

> [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray
>   arrayWithObject:tracksKey] completionHandler:
>        ^{
>            // The completion block goes here.
>        }];

And there should be a 'duration' key in the array.

When loading completes, get the duration with

> Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([<#An asset#> duration]);

Answer (score 1):

> For Swift 3.0 and above

import AVFoundation

```
  let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: ("Your File Path here")!))
  let totalSeconds = Int(CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration))
  let minutes = totalSeconds / 60
  let seconds = totalSeconds % 60
  let mediaTime = String(format:"%02i:%02i",minutes, seconds)
```